# Dropdown UI Element Names

Tags: terminology, component, library, pattern-library

I'm building a new dropdown, and I want to make the parts modular for ease of customization but having a hard time with names.

A popover wraps everything. Inside that popover is a  that is the trigger. I am trying to name this button that can be square or rounded, include have an icon or not, be just an icon and no text, and the value will be a compound name or a single name. We called this component a selector but the name could be better

Comment: I think it will be easier to answer if you attach an image of what you explain in the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.